# INSERT INTO pdo from web-form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why my insert-form isn't works?

```
public function safeCar() {

    $asd = "INSERT INTO 
        'Car'(mark,
        model,
        year,
        state_num,
        mileage,
        colour,
        consumption,
        cost_less_30_inc,
        cost_more_31) 
        VALUES('$this->mark', 
        '$this->model', 
        $this->year, 
        $this->state_num, 
        $this->mileage, 
        '$this->colour', 
        $this->consumption,
        $this->cost_less_30, 
        $this->cost_more_31)";
    echo($asd);

    $this->db->prepare($asd)->execute();
```

I'm sending form via POST and trying to add data into DB. But php sent me a error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in ...
>
> #### ..

But my string looks so good

> INSERT INTO 'Car'(mark, model, year, state_num, mileage, colour, consumption, cost_less_30_inc, cost_more_31) VALUES('Fiat', 'Punto', 2003, 345, 32929, 'black', 7, 10, 7)
>
> #### it works in phpMyAdmin

Where I made a mistake?

> var - db its PDO object

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: ok, I got it. But it just study project

Answer (score 0):

```
 $prepare = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Car (mark, model, year,state_num,mileage,colour, consumption, cost_less_30_inc, cost_more_31) 
        VALUES (:mark, :model, :year, :state_num,:mileage,:colour,:consumption,:cost_less_30_inc,:cost_more_31)");

$prepare->execute(array(
    'mark' => 'Honda',
    'year' => 2016,
     ...
     ...
);
```

Comment: I did it but it isn't works :(
Connection with db is ok, my 'select' queries works great

Comment: i edited, try this and have you take error output?

Comment: Yes, the error is similar.. I've already tried to do it like that

Comment: I did it! My var "db" was static and it must be calling by self:: 
But all the same tx to u.

Comment: ah i see, ure welcome:)